Springboot Isolate readiness from liveness probe
Is there a way in Springboot to isolate the readiness probe computation from the liveness probe computation?
Typically the readiness probe has more risk to take long, e.g. when database connectivity checks time out, while the liveness probe is typically supposed to be more lightweight and be less affected by infrastructure issues. However, both typically share the same threadpool, i.e. if there are too many requests in too short a time to the readiness endpoint when it is slow, the liveness endpoint might take too long to respond and the application might be considered not alive, when it actually should be considered alive. Is there a way to separate both checks from each other?
Options I would see:

configure a separate threadpool to be used for both types of endpoints
or at least limiting the time spent per call for the readiness health check

The server used is undertow and the actuator endpoints already run on a separate port from the main application and thus have their own (small) threadpool. Thus they are isolated from the regular workload but not from each other.

Both checks come with timeouts. Separate threadpool has nothing to do with anything.

They all use the request handling pools, which has about 200 threads... If that isn't enough you are doing way to many requests...

@M.Deinum the point of the readiness probe is exactly to detect (among other things) too many requests being handled by one pod/instance getting too many requests so one can correct the issue (either by filtering malicious requests or scaling up for instance)

@AbhijitSarkar if there are configurable timeouts for the readiness health check, that would be an answer if you can point them out, I haven't found any yet

I know what the probes are for. Unless you are running them on totally different ports and connectors they will share the same thread pool. Adding just another won't change a thing if you don't run them in a seperate connector instance (assuming Tomcat here) because the request handling pool will still be shared then. You should probably extend the timeout for the liveness probe (which is on the kubernetes side of things).

@M.Deinum they already run on a separate port and thus are separated from the regular worker thread pool (running on Undertow) but not separated from each other.

It turns out both features (separating computation of the status and request handling as well as timelimits for computation of the status) have been requested by other users and are under consideration by spring. You can check out these issues to track the progress on these issues:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25459
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/43449
In addition the tests currently run sequentially and running them parallel is also under consideration here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2652
Since all of these issues are already open for a while, the threads mention a few ways to implement the respective behavior on the application side overwriting the existing status checks.
In particular, there is also this library that combines these features and allows to use them for any health check via annotation: https://github.com/antoinemeyer/spring-boot-async-health-indicator
Note that it still would need you to overwrite any existing status checks to apply the different behavior to them (and disable the default version).
